# error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void> | JQueryPromise<void>'

Tags: angular, angular7, typescript-typings, devextreme-angular

I am using a `remove` method to emit a value to store. But getting an error as 
`error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void> | JQueryPromise<void>'.` - how to fix this?

here the sample what i use:

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CRUDOperations/Angular/Light/

here is my ts code :

```
ngOnChanges() {

        if (!this.subsystems) { return; }

        this.dataSource = new CustomStore({
            key: 'Id',
            load: (loadOptions) => this.loadData(loadOptions),
            update: (key: number, values) => this.updateData(key, values),
            remove: (key) => this.removeData(key) //getting error here
        });

    }

    loadData(loadOptions) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.dataGrid.columns = this.columns;
            resolve({ data: this.subsystems, totalCount: 10 });
        });
    }

    removeData(key: any) {
        this.deleteId.emit(key);
    }
```

[image: error attached]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise | JQueryPromise'

Then have the function underlined in red return a promise.

```
    removeData(key: any) {
        this.deleteId.emit(key);
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
```

That's a quick and somewhat dirty fix, though. Ideally, that promise would be resolved only after whoever listens to `this.deleteId` concluded all his business (but if nothing asynchronous happens there, you should be fine).

Comment: This was useful within a stub for testing purposes!